# setting one worksheet cell range reference to another worksheet using aspose.cells or MS-Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2003, aspose, aspose-cells

I want to set one worksheet cell range reference to another worksheet using aspose.cells or MS-Excel.For example i have two worksheet(wrk1 and wr2). I have some data on wrk1 and wrk2 is balnk.Now on wrk2 i want cells refrence of wrk1(like want cell reference of wrk1 sheet A1:A10 on wrk2 with same style as on wrk1) .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the following already?
[Copy the data and formatting of a particular range of cells](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/copy-range-data-with-style.html)

If this doesn't help then please share some more details regarding your requirement. You may also [contact our support team](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx) directly for getting help on Aspose.Cells.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.